Can a name introduced via using-directive or using-declaration be used as elaborated-type-specifier of a friend declaration?
Why do gcc, clang and msvc successfully compile the following code? (godbolt)
namespace impl {
class A;
} // namespace impl

namespace api {
using namespace impl;
} // namespace api

class B
{
    friend class api::A;     // (1)
};

The way I see it, this particular kind of friend declaration requires elaborated-type-specifier. Elaborated-type-specifier is class keyword followed by class name. But there's no class with the name api::A in this translation unit. Using-directive doesn't declare such class, it only affects name lookup rules. So I would expect that compilation of line marked (1) fails with error that there's no class A in namespace api. But major compilers accept it... What am I missing?
And the followup question: if I replaced using-directive using namespace impl; with using-declaration using impl::A;, that would really declare name A in namespace api, thus making the code well-formed?

What do you mean by "elaborate", there is nothing missing this is a totally normal way of "re-directing/aliasing" namespaces. Also you use the tag "language-lawyer" that is totally not necessary here. There is no language ambiguity here that needs clarification. With "api::A" you are basically telling the compiler, look in namespace api... which just has pulled in ALL of namespace impl ... so it can find ANY symbol from namespace impl as if it was in namespace api.

At [class.mem.general] I udnerstand that a friend-type-declaration is of the form friend friend-type-specifier-list; where friend-type-specifier-list, where friend-type-specifier-list can be a single friend-type-specifier, which can in turn be an elaborated-type-specifier, but also a simple-type-specifier or a typename-specifier.

@PepijnKramer, but they way you put it, makes it look like using namespace impl; and a sequence of using impl::entity; for every single entity in namespace impl would have the same effect (i.e. "has pulled in ALL of..."). But the question is precisely about whether the two scenarii should be the same indeed, or not.

The OP is asking why friend class api::A; is valid even if api::A was never declared anywhere. Or, in other words, why doesn't a friend declaration require that the name be a declared name? I guess the answer is simply that friend class foo; only requires foo to be visible to look up. But I don't know how to formulate a language-lawyer answer.

I think friend class api::A; is friendship of a forward declaration of a class A in api.  Not 100% sure if that works for qualified names.

http://eel.is/c++draft/namespace.qual#1.sentence-2?

A name lookup for the name api::A finds a class declaration, so therefore there is too a class named api::A.

@Enlico yes, it seems that the explanation I was looking for is that friend declaration with elaborated-type-specifier is well-formed if what the name lookup finds is a class.

First of, class api::A in your friend declaration is an elaborated-type-specifier.
But regardless, even if you drop class so that it isn't an elaborated-type-specifier anymore, lookup of names in a friend declaration is done just like any other lookup. Lookup of names (whether qualified or unqualified) in an elaborated-type-specifier is also done as usual. (There are specific rules in each case, but none which matter here.)
Only if lookup for an unqualified name in an elaborated-type-specifier doesn't find anything or if the whole declaration has certain specific forms in which the elaborated-name-specifier is the whole declaration, then it declares a class/enum with the name in some target scope.
Lookup for api::A from the class scope finds ::impl::A and so the friend declaration refers to that class (whether or not the class keyword is used).

In order to understand what is happening, we must look at each element of your code:
namespace impl {
    class A;
};

is a namespace that declares class A.
namespace api {
    using namespace impl;
};

is a namespace that uses namespace impl, which has class A declared inside of it.
class B
{
    friend class api::A;     // (1)
};

is a class that has a declaration, that tells the compiler, that class A, which is in namespace api, which uses namespace impl, is a friend of class B.
It's essentially a chain. B::api -> api::impl -> impl::A.
